# How to correctly implement and access various custom enumerators of operators?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enumeration

I'm trying to create several enums in order to quickly compare parsed tokens based on precedence.

This is the code I have so far in main.cpp:

```
    enum openParen0 : char { op = '(', ob = '[', oc = '{' };
    enum closedParen0 : char { cp = ')', cb = ']', cc = '}' };
    enum oper1 : char { plus = '+', minus = '-' };
    enum oper2 : char { mult = '*', div = '/', mod = '%' };

    openParen0 Open = op;
    closedParen0 Closed = cp;
    oper1 Operator1 = plus;
    oper2 Operator2 = mult;

    int problem, num1 = 5, num2 = 2;
    problem = Open + num1 + Operator1 + num1 + Closed + Operator2 + num2;

    cout << Open << num1 << " " << Operator1 << " " << num1 << Closed << " " << Operator2 << " " << num2 << " =" << endl;
    cout << problem;
```

I'm just wondering how to modify my code so I correctly output the calculations based on the enums. I'm new to this concept so I'm just trying to understand it.

This is the code I'm getting:

```
(5 + 5) * 2 =
178
```

Obviously, I'm expecting, instead:

```
(5 + 5) * 2 =
20
```

Thank you.

Comment: `problem = Open + num1 + Operator1 + num1 + Closed + Operator2 + num2;` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It just computes a sum of some integers and ASCII codes of some characters. The resulting number is largely meaningless. It certainly does *not* compute the result of the expression that the next line prints.

Comment: As to how to implement expression evaluation, see e.g. [the shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is there any way I can pass by reference / dereference to get it to work?

Comment: To pass what to what else to get what to work? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: If you want to write a parser, then you need to write a parser. Which is more than a few lines for mathematical operations. Or get some library that does this. Don't waste time trying to get this done like in your code so far, won't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to use`cout<<op;`, the output is the ASCII value corresponding to "("

Type char is an integral type that usually contains members of the basic execution character set — By default, this is ASCII in Microsoft C++.

According the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/enumerations-cpp?view=vs-2019):

> type
>
> The underlying type of the enumerators; all enumerators have the same
>   underlying type. May be any integral type.

As far as I'm concerned you couldn't enumerate symbols directly.